# Are chainsaw helmets meant to protect you from the saw, or just falling debris?

Tags: safety, protection, chainsaw

I'm trying to get the correct protective equipment for a chainsaw. I see helmets that look like this

[image: chain saw helmet]

being sold for chainsaw use, but it's not clear if they are meant to protect your face from the running saw in the event of kickback, or if they are just to stop woodchucks from getting in your face and protection from falling branches.

Are these meant to stop the saw from injuring your face/head in the same way that chaps protect the legs?

Comment: Have you ever seen a picture of the osha cowboy? This helmet would meet those requirements, Kevlar chaps and ear plugs or hearing protection are what the crew use at the mill I work at.

Comment: the helmet should stop glancing blows from the saw blade, like backing into someone sawing or dropping a running saw on someone's head. It's not like the special saw-killing sacrificial chaps though, it's just a tough slippery helmet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helmet is designed to protect you from falling objects. It is also the mounting point for the face shield and ear protection.  The helmet will also provide limited protection from the saw in the event the saw were to kick-back or the operator lost control and the chain were to impact the operators' head.  It will not provide protection from a running saw being held against the helmet. This differs from safety chaps which are designed to actually stop a saw in the event of contact with the chaps.

Answer (score 0):

The helmet is meant to provide protection from head injuries caused by falls and a chainsaw kickback that can occur and from flying objects that can be projected such as twigs and branches from the tree being cut.

Anyone operating a chainsaw or working near a tree-cutting or trimming work-site should wear an approved helmet, preferably a hard hat that is highly visible in color and has a chin strap to prevent it from falling off.  Helmets should be worn at all times, whether working on the ground or in the air.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing, accepted, answer.